# Re factoring jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can refactor this below jQuery code.
All the functions does the same job but on different key-presses on the table search box. Which is filtering the table data.
I want re factor this code and write it in single function. Please help me.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // when the #name field changes
    $("body").on("keypup", "#name",  function() {
      var form = $("#users_form"); // grab the form wrapping the name bar.
      var url = form.attr("action");
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $.get(url, formData, function(data) { 
          $("#reseller_admin_list").html(data); // replace the "results" div with the result of action taken
      });
       $("body").on("keypup", "#login",  function() {
      var form = $("#users_form"); // grab the form wrapping the name bar.
      var url = form.attr("action");
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $.get(url, formData, function(data) { 
          $("#reseller_admin_list").html(data); // replace the "results" div with the result of action taken
      });

     $("body").on("keypup", "#account_manager",  function() {
      var form = $("#users_form"); // grab the form wrapping the name bar.
      var url = form.attr("action");
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $.get(url, formData, function(data) { 
          $("#reseller_admin_list").html(data); // replace the "results" div with the result of action taken
      });

     $("body").on("keypup", "#email",  function() {
      var form = $("#users_form"); // grab the form wrapping the name bar.
      var url = form.attr("action");
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $.get(url, formData, function(data) { 
          $("#reseller_admin_list").html(data); // replace the "results" div with the result of action taken
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: you should probably post this to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)
At a glance, your handler functions look very similar, they can probably be refactored into a single parametrized function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function update() {
  var form = $("#users_form"); // grab the form wrapping the name bar.
  var url = form.attr("action");
  var formData = form.serialize();
  $.get(url, formData, function(data) { 
      $("#reseller_admin_list").html(data); // replace the "results" div with the result of action taken
  });
}

$("body").on("keyup", "#account_manager, #login, #email", update);
```

**The explanation:**

1.) We extract the duplicate code in a single function called *update*. We  follow the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) here

2.) JQuery allows us to use [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), so we can bind the *update* function to all elements at once:

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#account_manager, #login, #email", update);
```

instead of calling:

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#account_manager", update);
$("body").on("keyup", "#login", update);
$("body").on("keyup", "#email", update);
```

Comment: You have my upvote, but maybe you should add an explanation why you did what you did and why it works. I know how it works, but OP might not.

Comment: Agree! Explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

how about just having one code block:

```
$("body").on("keypup", "#name, #login, #account_manager, #email", function() {
      var form = $("#users_form"); 
      var url = form.attr("action");
      var formData = form.serialize();
      $.get(url, formData, function(data) { 
          $("#reseller_admin_list").html(data); 
      });
});
```

Much better though, would be to give you elements a class, and bind to the class rather then each id, i.e.

`$("body").on("keypup", ".someClass", function() { //etc`

Answer (score 0):

write a new function.

```
$("body").on("keypup", "#login", function() {
  functionName();
});
```

and in function

```
function functionName(){

 var form = $("#users_form"); // grab the form wrapping the name bar.
  var url = form.attr("action");
  var formData = form.serialize();
  $.get(url, formData, function(data) { 
      $("#reseller_admin_list").html(data); // replace the "results" div with the result of action taken
  });`
}
```

Comment: You realise you can just pass the function `functionName` without quotes to the callback parameter in jQuery? No need for a nested function to call it.

Comment: you can also use `$("body").on("keypup", "#account_manager, #login, #email", functionName);`